# mongodb: copy array property from one object to the other

Tags: mongodb

I need to do some maintenance on a mongo DB. We are in the middle of development so no issue about data integrity etc. when directly fiddling with the DB.

I have an object `Store`, which has a property "`item_list`".

One `Store` object, say `x`, has an invalid `item_list`. Another `Store`, `y`, has a valid `item_list`. I'd like to copy the `item_list` from `y` to `x` in `mongo`'s command line client.

In `mongo`, when I try to access the property, it doesn't work: when I do

```
db.Store.find({name:'x'})
```

mongo returns the complete object, but

`db.Store.find({name:'x'}).item_list`

doesn't return anything.

How can I copy y's item_list to x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach you could take is using the **[`find()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** cursor method **[`forEach()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/#cursor.forEach)** to iterate the cursor and access the documents and their properties, update the other documents, as in the following example:

```
db.Store.find({"name": "y"}).forEach(function(doc){
    db.Store.update(
        { "name": "x" },
        { "$set": { "item_list": doc.item_list } },
        { "multi": true }
    )
})
```